# Construction of a linear transformation with specific kernel and image

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I got stuck on this exercise and its really frustrating :/

It says something like this:

> Given W={p(x) ∈ P₂[R] : P(1)=P(-1)} a linear transformation f:P₂[R]
>   --> P₂[R] is required such that Ker(f) will be W
>
> 1)What should i know about W to know if i can get any linear
>   transformation with the previous information?
>
> 2)Is it possible to get the linear transformation such that the
>   polynomial h[x]= X will belong to Im(f)?

I dont understand the exercise.. take a look:

For 1) i think i should know the basis of W because its a linear transformation

I did this:

```
P₂[R]=ax^2 + bx + c

P(1)-P(-1)=0

a + b + c - (a - b + c)=0

a + b + c - a + b - c = 0

2b = 0

b=0

Then,

P₂[R]=ax^2 + c P₂[R]=a(x^2) + c(1)

Basis=(x^2,1)
```

What should i do now? I have no idea what to do :(...

What about point 2)?

Thanks!!

Comment: 1) is not quite right. I mean, it's obvious in this simple case, but first you should check that $W$ is a subspace. Check it is closed for addition, multiplacation etc. THEN you find a basis.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to define an appropriate application on the basis vectors. For instance, you want $W$ to be the kernel, right? Then take the basis $\{x^2,x,1 \}$ and send $x^2$ and $1$ to $0$ and $x$ in $x$. This way the kernel is $W$ and $Span(x)$ is the image.

Comment: Thank you for replying!
I still dont get it, dude.. :(

Comment: You're welcome. Let's do this step-by-step. 1) You know that every linear function is completely defined when defined over a basis 2) You find a basis (for instance the one I wrote above) 3)You send things in a way that gives you what is required. You want $Span(x^2,1)$ to be the kernel? No problem, I just define the application so that they go to zero. Want $Span(x)$ to be the image? No problem, I have another vector in the basis that I need to send somewhere. I just choose to send him in the right place

Comment: Okay, please.. its really frustrating. I feel stupid :(

Comment: @JustToKnow don't worry, linear algebra is hard at first, but once understood it gets easier. What of the steps above you don't get?

Comment: How can i know if with the given information i will be able to determine a linear transformation?How can i get it?Why did you choose span(x^2,1) ONLY with 2 elements?

Comment: Why span(x) is the image?

Comment: There is not a unique transformation, indeed. For instance, you could send $x$ to $2x$ and still be fine. You want to find if it exists at least one linear transformation with such properties (the text is misleading, you are asking to find the linear transformation as if it were unique).

Comment: But, for example.. what would be the linear transformation?

Comment: Span(x) is the image because you choose him to be. Because you are requested to do so. Again, you have to find a linear application whose kernel is $Span(x^2,1)$ and whose image is $Span(x)$. You take a basis, for instance the one above, and send each element of the basis in a way that the linear transformation you get satisfies the requests. Try to write it down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73450/discussion-between-justtoknow-and-tommy1996q).